# Changing the language in Site Language does nothing

Tags: options

Wordpress should always allow me to change the language, anytime. However, when I try to change the language to Greek, the language stays English, as it is now.

How can I overcome that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have a custom language set for your user because now in WordPress you can change it globally and per-user: https://cl.ly/jNvo - it's possible that setting may be overriding the global one.

Comment: That was it, thank you, but unfortunately I still have a problem with woocommerce.
Some of the text is still not visible in Greek language, even though I've included the Greek woocommerce translation files (mostly in buttons and cart related text).
Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Try changing themes, sometimes your theme will modify some of the WooCommerce files so you actually have to translate your theme as well.